# Unable to connect "Canon PIXMA MG3650S" to the local WiFi-network. DIRECT-WLAN of the printer is not found in the list of the "Canon PRINT"-app

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printing, printer, network-printer

I have bought the printer "Canon Pixma MG3650S" from Aldi Online Shop. I set up the printer, connected it to electricity, and turned it on. I downloaded the "Canon PRINT"-App from the Play Store to my Android phone in order to connect the new printer to my home WiFi-network. I opened the app, granted all the permissions, and clicked on "register a new printer". Then, a list shows up with the DIRECT-WLAN of several printers, which are apparently from my neighbors, but my own printer does not show up. The same list of DIRECT-WLAN connections of my neighbors' printers apppears in the WLAN settings of my phone, where I, for instance, connect with my own router, but my new printer doesn't show up either.

For this situation, the manual offers a solution (the instruction can also be found online): a re-instanciation of the printer - in layman's terms. You should press the WiFi-button of the printer, hold it pressed, and wait until the on/off-button starts flashing, in the first step, then follow a few further steps. When I do this, the printer doesn't behave as expected. In fact, I press and keep pressing the WiFi-button but nothing happens. The on/off-button doesn't start flashing.

After all this, how can I connect the printer to my local WiFi-network?

PS. I tried to restart the printer and the phone several times. Nothing changes!
[image: Then, a list shows up with the DIRECT-WLAN of several printers, which are apparently from my neighbors, but my own printer does not show up.]

[image: The same list of DIRECT-WLAN connections of my neighbors' printers apppears in the WLAN settings of my phone, where I, for instance, connect with my own router, but my new printer doesn't show up either.]

[image: The same list of DIRECT-WLAN connections of my neighbors' printers apppears in the WLAN settings of my phone, where I, for instance, connect with my own router, but my new printer doesn't show up either.]

[image: For this situation, the manual offers a solution (the instruction can also be found online): a re-instanciation of the printer - in layman's terms.]

[image: You should press the WiFi-button of the printer, hold it pressed, and wait until the on/off-button starts flashing, in the first step, then follow a few further steps.]

Comment: Your [manual](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/2/0300019362/02/MG3600ser_OnlineManual_Win_EN_V02.pdf) says that to connect to the printer via wifi you need to enable Access Point Mode, as described on page 469. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I read the manual. It is also in the pictures. But as I wrote: For this situation, the manual offers a solution (the instruction can also be found online): a re-instanciation of the printer - in layman's terms. You should press the WiFi-button of the printer, hold it pressed, and wait until the on/off-button starts flashing, in the first step, then follow a few further steps. When I do this, the printer doesn't behave as expected. In fact, I press and keep pressing the WiFi-button but nothing happens. The on/off-button doesn't start flashing. @harrymc

Comment: I would suggest to connect the printer to a computer via USB, verify that it works, install whatever software exists to update the printer's firmware, then test. If it doesn't work, then ask Canon Support for help, and if there's no solution then return the printer (if possible) or leave it connected to the computer. These are the only possibilities that I can see.